# Vb.net two comma separated lists

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, csv, subroutine

I am being passed two strings that contain comma separated lists.

```
string1 (1,2,3,4)
String2 (Red, blue, yellow, purple)
```

I want to pass each pair to another routine to process them. The strings can change along with the index.

I have to split each string value and loop through both so that I could pass each pair to a subroutine

Comment: `Private Sub MyRoutine(str1 As String, str2 As String)` then pass them: `MySub( string1, string2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Split` to get each component between the commas and pass this:

```
    Dim string1 As String = "1,2,3,4"
    Dim string2 As String = "Red,blue,yellow,purple"

    Dim string1AsArray = string1.Split(","c)
    Dim string2AsArray = string2.Split(","c)

    For i = 0 To string1AsArray.Count - 1
        MyRoutine(string1AsArray(i), string2AsArray(i))
    Next
```

you may want to check that both of the arrays are the same size otherwise you may get an exception thrown

Comment: thanks so simple. I split everything was going to loop using for each and got stuck. Makes sense using the index.